# how to write php code in drupal view

Tags: views

In my drupal site I need to restrict the access of a view to certain users.
The senario is like, each user will be assigned to a certain Item. Each item is a view.
The users relation to the items is defined in a mysql table.
Now what I need is, When ever a user clicks on a pirticular view (item) I need to check if he has access to that. Where can I write the code for this ?

Comment: This is what permissions are for. Grant only certain users the right to access the view.

Comment: Yes..I have a custom table and a custom module for doing so

Comment: If possible can you share the table structure and values?

Comment: It may be easier to achieve this using Drupal's built in roles and permissions. The views UI has an option for choosing which permission users must have to be able to view the content.